# Halakha for mourning a stillborn child

Tags: halacha, death, baby-infant

I have a short amount of time to find recent Halakha on **Orthodox and Conservative** guidance on **mourning a stillbirth**.  Any pointers greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2432015/jewish/Post-mortem-Naming-and-Circumcision-for-a-Stillbirth.htm https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=691 this last one recaps Orthodox and presents Conservative https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/stillbirth-and-neonatal-death/

Comment: Hi Karen and welcome to Mi Yodeya! This is a very difficult subject, and I hope that you find the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @rosends - why not make that an answer?

Comment: http://www.hakirah.org/vol23Weiner.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.shamash.org/lists/scj-faq/HTML/faq/21-02-07.html) may help perhaps.
It features the traditional Torah perspective. It also quotes a few opinions from both reform and conservative.